# opening a dynamic php page with ajax with href without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Now my question is simple not seen any sooting on stack overflow site. How do i open a dynamic PHP page with Ajax and also if the Ajax fails too open the page  normally, just like google. If their search fails lets imagine they use  Ajax they automatically run the page how do i do that through a Href link 
No page refresh and if it fails load normally please help i am stuck. Not a duplicate not seen any answer please help I am stuck..

```
    example
   <a href="onelink.php" >Open me</a>

           //current page onelink.php
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Your href will work as you have it - where does Ajax come into it?

Comment: @RGriffiths i have updated the question sorry for the question error

Comment: I will give you an hint. Learn about e.PreventDefault. Also, do you know how to do an Ajax call? Show us what you have tried so far. Last but not least there are thousands of questions like your on SO already

Comment: Again, I do not understand what you are trying to do. Are you just trying to change part of your page without a full refresh? You need to show more of your code. What have you tried?

Comment: @RGriffiths yes i am trying to that that go through pages with ajax that alls without page refresh

Comment: @RGriffiths I am trying to do it like Instagram web or google whe you do a search and probably you have a slow connection it then runs and use refresh else it just opens the page with ajax like google instant

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a short answer because I've already seen some really great answers to this sort of question on this site and if you continue to search in the tags that you have listed especially jquery ajax then I'm sure that you get what you need.  The jquery.ajax() page at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ might be a good place to start.  If you want to really understand this your going to have to do some studying.  That said here's some old code of mine.

This is an ajax request for some information sent from the client side to a php file on the server.  Whether the page is dynamically generated or real doesn't really matter as long as it's something that responds to the requested URL.

```
function logrequest()
    {
            $.ajax({
               url: siteURL + '/custom/log/requestlog.php',
               type: 'GET',
               data: $.param({ip: customer_ip}),
               dataType: 'json',
               success: function(data){
                     if(data.count!=null)
                     {
                            requests=data.count;
                     }
               }
        });
    }
```

And the following is the response from a php file name requestlog.php.

```
<?php
$ip=$_GET['ip'];
$ip_passS=file_get_contents('http://www...passthru.txt');
$ip_passA=split(',',$ip_passS);
$ip_cnt=0;
$d=gmdate("ymd");
$RQLog=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/custom/log/requests/RQLog'.$d.'.txt';
$fp=fopen($RQLog,"a");
$s=gmdate("H:i:s").", ".$ip."\r\n";
fwrite($fp,$s);
fclose($fp);
$ip_requests=file_get_contents('http://www.../custom/log/requests/RQLog'.$d.'.txt');
$ip_cnt=substr_count($ip_requests,$ip);
header('Content-Type: text/json');
if(!in_array($ip,$ip_passA))
{
    $response = array('count'=>$ip_cnt);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
else  //if your in the passthru, you get a free lunch
{
    $response = array('count'=>0);
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

So the ajax requested data from the PHP file and the file on the server responded by echoing the data back to it in json format.  In some cases depending upon where the request is going you may never receive a response.  Like if your dealing with a site can converts addresses to GPS coordinates.  If they get busy and your low priority you may never get a response but your code can go merrily on it's way.   If you continue to generate too many of these requests however you may run into some limits which are both browser imposed and server imposed so you need to understand what your doing.

But that's the short answer.

The value of doing something this way is that this sort of thing could be content for a small portion of your screen on your website if it doesn't respond right away you can just keep on loading your page and the data will be provided when it's returned.

The details of this code are not important. The question was "how do you open up a php page (dynamic or otherwise) with ajax.  The answer is by passing the correct url to the ajax request and the page returns it's data by echoing it.  It could be a click on button or the document ready event once the DOM has loaded.  It could be a lot things.  You have to decided what you want it to be.  By the way, debugging this kind of code can be very difficult so be patient.

#### The Rest of the Question

So the part of the question I didn't answer was what to do if the page on the server **doesn't open** or **doesn't ever send a response**.  So one problem could be that the page did open and run but didn't send back the response that you expected or perhaps there was an uncaught error during the response. I find these situations are often difficult to trouble shoot so sometimes I'll setup response log and log all responses to the success and failure routines if they both exist.  In that way I can hopefully determine how to improve the code.   You can also pass an error object to your javascript routines and depending upon the types of errors your getting (assuming your logging them) you might be able to gain some insight to the problem.  But the short answer is to either fix your code or figure out a way to issue another request.  If your authoring both the client side and the server side you can use try/catch a lot to see if you can capture the problem.  If your not authoring the server side then read as much as you can about their API or interface and pay attention to errors returned.

So most of the time I find that other peoples public access interfaces do talk back to me but I have to know how to listen. When I'm writing the server side code I almost always try to keep it dirt simple because I don't often expect to get too much traffic in these situations and if I expect a lot of traffic I'll usually opt for a commercially available solution (i.e. *Someone who really knows what they're doing*).

Comment: thank you for the code but please break it down for me really dont understand what fires logrequest(); is an onclick on the href,  and secondly would i include requestlog in my file and in the ajax i see you are passing ip: custom ip would i have to detect that also myself and i also that www...passthru.txt is it the link that was clicked or would i have a file named that please i dont understand teach me like a beginner i want to learn this been trying all i can no answer solution @Cooper

Comment: made a comment above